# Vue in docker container doesn't install devDependencies using yarn

Tags: vue.js, docker-compose, yarnpkg

Hello I have initialized a vue app in docker container, set-up the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`, test it and commit to repo.

After I clone the repo on other device and run `docker-compose up --build`, yarn will not install any `devDependencies`...

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: 'develop-stage'
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    command: /bin/sh -c "yarn serve"
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:11.1-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install --all
COPY . .
```

While running the `yarn install --all` I will have this warning:

> warning @vue/cli-plugin-eslint > eslint > file-entry-cache >
>   flat-cache > circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only,
>   flatted is its successor.

When running `yarn serve`  it will exit with this error:

> frontend_1  | yarn run v1.12.1
>
> frontend_1  | $ vue-cli-service serve --port 8090
>
> frontend_1  | /bin/sh: vue-cli-service: not found
>
> frontend_1  | error Command failed with exit code 127

How can I install all the `devDependencies`?

Comment: I think I see what's going on. Your `docker-compose.yml` mounts the local directory to `/app` so anything that _was_ in `/app` from the build stage is lost

Comment: @Phil so I just need to remove the volumes from `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: That might make it work but it won't be able to hot-reload your code as it updates

Comment: Thanks! I  was using this tutorial ~ https://medium.com/@jwdobken/vue-with-docker-initialize-develop-and-build-51fad21ad5e6

Comment: Have a read of this https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-vue-app/

Answer (score 0):

just use something like this in :

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      target: 'develop-stage'
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
    volumes:
      - './src:/app/src'
    command: /bin/sh -c "yarn serve"
```

It will keep node_modues in app forlder